# Not able to find juju charm mysql root password?

Tags: mysql, juju

I tried to follow the steps mentioned in mysql charm:

```
$ juju ssh <unit> mysql -u root -p
enter root password:
```

`/var/lib/juju/mysql.passwd`

But after installing `mysql charm`, /var/lib/juju/mysql.passwd file was not there.
Kindly help locating `mysql` root password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the mysql.passwd file was moved to `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.passwd` but the README was not updated. I've submitted a patch to the charm to update the README. However, you should be able to `juju ssh mysql/0` and `cat /var/lib/mysql/mysql.passwd` to get the current MySQL root password.

Comment: any idea on the current charm..? I dont find any mysql folder in the lib directory ..

Answer (score 0):

From the juju controller run the following command to get all mysql passwords

```
juju run --unit mysql/0 leader-get
```